# C# Regular Expression - Extracting the number of month or year from codes

Tags: c#, regex

I would like only one regular expression to extract the number of days, weeks, months and/or years from the following codes:

```
AB7YT1M=ABC       ==> 7Y1M

AB10YT1M=ABC      ==> 10Y1M

AB30YT1M=ABC      ==> 30Y1M

ABCDEF1Y1M=A      ==> 1Y1M

ABCDEF34Y6M=A     ==> 34Y6M

ABCDEF7M=A        ==> 7M

ABCDEF1D=A      ==> 1D


@"(\d+[DWMY])(?!\w+(1))(\d+[DWMY])(?!\w+(1))|(\d+[DWMY])(?!\w+(1))"
```

This code does not support e.g. 30YT1M

Could someone please help find an appropriate regexp for me?

Comment: I have just tried this regexp (\d+[DMWY])T?((\d+)[DMWY])|((\d+)[DMWY]) because the string is operated from right to left but it seems i need to remove the "T" string from e.g. 10YT1M -> 10Y1M  Could someone please help check this regexp if it is a proper regexp and let me know if there is a way to remove the "T" string from only one expression? Then i do not need to have another operation to remove "T".

Comment: You say `days` (e.g. `1D`?), weeks (e.g. `1W`?? no example provided), `months` (e.g. `6M`), and/or `years` (e.g. `1Y`). Now, the question is, are they always in the same order? What parts are obligatory, which are optional? What .NET version are you using? 4.5?

Comment: @stribizhev yes it is smth like 1.3 years(1Y3M) 1.3 weeks (1W3D) or 3 months (3M) i would like regexp that supports both .Net 4 & 4.5

Answer (score 3):

This expression will do the trick ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gN4jU4/2)):

```
(?:(\d+)Y)?T?(?:(\d+)M)
```

In order to get just the data that you need, get the content of the first and the second capturing groups. When the corresponding entry is present in the string, the first group would contain the year, and the second would contain the month ([demo](http://ideone.com/A8zKwN)):

```
var data = new[] {
    "AB7YT1M=ABC",
    "AB10YT1M=ABC",
    "AB30YT1M=ABC",
    "ABCDEF1Y1M=A",
    "ABCDEF34Y6M=A",
    "ABCDEF7M=A"
};
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?:(\d+)Y)?T?(?:(\d+)M)");
foreach (var s in data) {
    var m = r.Match(s);
    if (m.Success) {
        var yy = m.Groups[1];
        var mm = m.Groups[2];
        Console.WriteLine("Y='{0}', M='{1}'", yy, mm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What if i add (?:(\d+[DMWY]))?T?(?:(\d+)[DMWY]) using [ ] character class. Does this impact processing time or memory? Should i use grouping construct instead?   Note that D and W represent Day and Week respectively..

Comment: @Ben If you use `[DMWY]` you wouldn't know what group corresponds to which duration. If the order is pre-defined, i.e. year before month, month before day, and so on, you can expand the expression from the answer to include other parts (`W`, `D`, etc.) as well. The reason the code above can grab group #1 and say that it's a year is that there's a `Y` that's required to be there after a non-empty group #1.

Comment: Thank you. I'm very new to this area. I have other questions. (Q1) From your code ?T? i'm not sure if this means any characters (zero or more) before and after the "T" (Q2). If i want just 10Y1M from 10YT1M can I put only ? between the two groups like this (?:(\d+[DMWY]))?(?:(\d+)[DMWY])?

Comment: @Ben The first `?` in `?T?` belongs to the group in front, making it optional i.e. `(?:(\d+)Y)?`. This should answer the second question, too: you need `T?` if you wish to allow for optional character `T` to be present.

Comment: It is not a good idea to make all sub patterns optional, regex won't work then. To get the full matched string use Group 0.

Comment: I have just tried this regexp (\d+[DMWY])T?((\d+)[DMWY])|((\d+)[DMWY]) because the string is operated from right to left but it seems i need to remove the "T" string from e.g. 10YT1M -> 10Y1M

Comment: @Ben Your regex matches `10YT1M` fine ([link to a demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ7qE7/1)). By the way, regex101 is a good tool to explore the way the changes to your regular expression change the matches that you get. Follow the first "demo" link from my answer for an illustration of how you can apply the same expression to multiple inputs (you need to put "g" in the box on the right of your expression).

Answer (score 0):

You can use named captures to make sure you match all the required values like this:

```
 (?:
     (?<Year>\d+)YT?
     |
     (?<Day>\d+)DT?
     |
     (?<Month>\d+)MT?
     |
     (?<Week>\d+)WT?
   )+
```

`T?` is added in case it appears right after the group we need.

See [demo on regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%3F%3CYear%3E%5Cd%2B)YT%3F%7C(%3F%3CDay%3E%5Cd%2B)DT%3F%7C(%3F%3CMonth%3E%5Cd%2B)MT%3F%7C(%3F%3CWeek%3E%5Cd%2B)WT%3F)%2B&i=AB7YT1M%3DABC%0D%0AAB7YT1M%3DABC%0D%0AAB10YT1M%3DABC%0D%0AAB30YT1M%3DABC%0D%0AABCDEF1Y1M%3DA%0D%0AABCDEF34Y6M%3DA%0D%0AABCDEF7M%3DA).